# failed update statement on Android

Tags: android

My application keeps a list of stock symbols. Recently i've noticed that for symbol "LOW" (Lowe's corp) the system is not able to update the table with latest value. I use following line to update the table

```
int i = db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_sym +"=\"" + item.sz_sym +"\"", null)  ;

 where DATABASE_TABLE = "Quote", KEY_sym = "symbol", item.sz_sym = "LOW" and args contains the new values.
```

I know for sure that it is due to symbol LOW, because it works for all other symbols. 
My question is, what's is happening here with the symbol LOW. and how do i resolve it. Also, is it possible to see what SQL statement is getting generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like,

```
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_sym+"=?", new String[]{item.sz_sym});
```

Comment: So your solution works. But my question is what's wrong with my initial approach?

Comment: Well, you can simply see the arguments what the `update()` requires, you where not passing the exact required arguments.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not comfortable with using syntax based sql statements, you could always use [ExecSql](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) to execute a plain sql query..